# how I can send email to my inbox via php in contact us page html

Tags: php, html, email

This is php code:

```
    <form action="form.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <h1 class="title">Contact</h1>

        <label></label>
        <input name="name" required="required" placeholder="Your Name">


        <label></label>
        <input name="email" type="email" required="required" placeholder="Your Email">


        <label></label>
        <textarea name="message" cols="20" rows="5" required="required" placeholder="Message"></textarea>


        <input id="cancel" name="cancel" value="Cancel" />

        <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">

    </form>
```

This is php code :

I have to set my email address but I cant receive the message. where is my coding wrong.

https://i.gyazo.com/c79a14dd8023b6a2f2ba4bddc85d19f9.png

Comment: None of what you posted is php.

Comment: Ah, the PHP code is a... PNG image.  Can you try "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" for enctype instead?  Unless you're using files, you probably shouldn't use multipart.

Comment: Please check your spam folder

Comment: spam also no.. php code in the image link.

Answer (score 0):

In from of Mail Function you need to set also e-mail address of sender not only the Name.

```
$headers = 'From: Jack Sparrow <jsparrow@blackpearl.com>' . PHP_EOL .
    'Reply-To: Jack Sparrow <jsparrow@blackpearl.com>' . PHP_EOL .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Comment: cannot, still no any email to my inbox.